# How can I accelerate my program trying to find the longest distance between random a million points?

Tags: c#

I am programming a program which calculate two points with the longest distance among one million points.
So firstly I wrote some codes as below :

```
private void computeLongestDistance()
    {

        double big = 0;
        double small = 0;
        double result;
        Points point1 = new Points();
        Points point2 = new Points();

        for(int i = 0; i < Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text); i++ )
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text); j++ )
            {
                result = Math.Sqrt(((points[i].coordX - points[j].coordX) * (points[i].coordX - points[j].coordX)) + ((points[i].coordY - points[j].coordY) * (points[i].coordY - points[j].coordY)));
                
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    big = result;
                    small = result;
                    point1 = points[i];
                    point2 = points[j];
                }
                if (small > result)
                {
                    small = result;
                }
                if (big < result)
                {
                    big = result;
                    point1 = points[i];
                    point2 = points[j];
                }
            }                
        }
```

After that, I noticed that the run-time is very hight so I searched and I found different way. And also, I wrote some code lines as below :

```
private void computeLongestDistance()
    {
        double big = 0;
        double small = 0;
        double result;
        Points point1 = new Points();
        Points point2 = new Points();          

        Parallel.For(0, Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text), new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount }, i =>
        {
            Parallel.For(0, Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text), new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount }, j =>
            {
                result = Math.Sqrt(((points[i].coordX - points[j].coordX) * (points[i].coordX - points[j].coordX)) + ((points[i].coordY - points[j].coordY) * (points[i].coordY - points[j].coordY)));

                if (i == 0)
                {
                    big = result;
                    small = result;
                    point1 = points[i];
                    point2 = points[j];
                }
                if (small > result)
                {
                    small = result;
                }
                if (big < result)
                {
                    big = result;
                    point1 = points[i];
                    point2 = points[j];
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

And after this codes, the program has accelerated but unfortunately it is not enough. Please can you give me some advice to speed-up the program.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it important that the result is completely accurate or would an approximation suffice?

Comment: This might help: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/109406/find-two-points-in-a-point-cloud-with-the-maximum-distance

Comment: @blenderfreaky Yes, the correct result is important but you can share your opinion. İt can inspire me.

Comment: My initial thoughts were about using quadtrees or calculating the center and doubling the distance to the furthest point. But it seems that the link above directly solves your problem in O(n log n + k) actually

Comment: @blenderfreaky Yes, you are right. I will solve this problem with O(n log n + k). Thank you so much. Is there a good resource you know to learn O(n log n + k)?

Comment: If by learning O(n log n + k) you mean learning the notation, just google Big-O notation. Here it basically means that the algorithm solves your problem in n log n + k steps, where n is the number of points and k is the number of vertices of the convex hull. The +k is actually not relevant here, see @Alexei Levenkov s comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as answer so the question can be marked as answered.

[This](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/109406/find-two-points-in-a-point-cloud-with-the-maximum-distance) solves the problem in O(n log n + k)

TL;DR:

- Calculate Convex Hull (O(n log n))
- Use the [Rotating Calipers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers) algorithm

Comment: Side note: O(n log n + k) is the same as O(n log n)... just pointing it out that while it makes more obvious where each part comes from, the  +k could be dropped : k <= n so n log n + k <= n (1 + log n) < 2 n log n,  and O(2 n log n) is equivalent to O(n log n)